# Replace Memory Issue VB.net

Tags: vb.net, memory, replace, streamwriter

i was kindly helped before with this code, however I have hit a stumbling block, and im not sure the correct way to go.  I have the code below which does a find and replace on over 120k of find and replaces.  The problem is the text file is HUGE easily over 5 gig of log files so i get a memory issue which is not surprise.  So do i load the data in blocks if that is even possible?, if so how.

---

```
Private Sub CmdBtnTestReplace_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdBtnTestReplace.Click
    Dim fName As String = "c:\backup\logs\master.txt"
    Dim wrtFile As String = "c:\backup\logs\masterUserFormatted.txt"
    Dim strRead As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
    Dim strWrite As New System.IO.StreamWriter(wrtFile)
    Dim s As String


    s = strRead.ReadToEnd()

    'runs through over 120k of find and replaces
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then

            Dim Find1 As String = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            Dim Replace1 As String = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

            'replace using string from 1st column and replaces with string from 2nd column.
            s = s.Replace(Find1, Replace1)

        End If

    Next

    strWrite.Write(s)
    strRead.Close()
    strWrite.Close()

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    MessageBox.Show("Finished Replacing")

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input file is a simple multi-line text file, where no individual line is too big to load into memory at once, and the search string is never going to span multiple lines, then reading only one line at a time will be the simplest solution.  For instance:

```
Dim fName As String = "c:\backup\logs\master.txt"
Dim wrtFile As String = "c:\backup\logs\masterUserFormatted.txt"
Dim strRead As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
Dim strWrite As New System.IO.StreamWriter(wrtFile)
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
While True
    Dim line As String = strRead.ReadLine()
    If line IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                Dim Find1 As String = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
                Dim Replace1 As String = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
                line = line.Replace(Find1, Replace1)
            End If
        Next
        strWrite.WriteLine(line)
    Else
        Exit While
    End If
End While
strRead.Close()
strWrite.Close()
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
MessageBox.Show("Finished Replacing")
```

It's worth mentioning that the `StreamReader` and `StreamReader` implement `IDisposable`.  As such, it would be preferable to enclose them in a `Using` block rather than explicitly calling `Close` yourself.

Comment: Hi Steve, Many thanks for your response, i have updated and tested but it does not seem to run through the find and replaces of whick there are over 100k. Kind Regards,

Comment: @vbvirg20 I've updated my answer to include a more complete example.  Let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: Steven you are a Star, thank you for your help and your explanation, clearly I need to do some more work on my loops. Many thanks again, VBvirg

Comment: Hi Steven I expanded the code to include cycling through some file dates from another datagrid but then i can get it to either cycle through and not find and replace or find and replace one of the files and not cycle through the rest of the files.  Where am i going wrong with the loops.?

Comment: The problem with that last example you posted in the (now deleted) "answer" is faulty because it first loops through all of the search/replace strings in the grid, and then for each one it loops through the file to do that current replace.  The only way that would work would be if you closed the files, and then opened the previous output file to use it as the input file for the next loop (which would be wildly inefficient).

Comment: The way I show in my answer works because it loops through each line in the file and then for each line, it loops through all of the search/replace strings in the grid and applies them all to that line before moving on to the next line.  In that way it only loops through the file once, which is far more efficient.   Reading the strings in the grid is very fast, since it's all in RAM.  Reading and writing to the file is much slower since it's on disk.

Comment: Than you Steve that is really helpful, i will master this yet :) im off to try some more loops now, thank you again.